# How to make filesystem as http.Handler

Tags: http, go, filesystems

I want to make a filesystem wrap in http.Handler.

```
type Handler func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

func (a *App) Handle(verb, path string, handler Handler) {
        ...
        h := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                ...
        }

        a.myRouter.HandleFunc(verb, path, h)
}

func (a *App) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a.myRouter.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func MYAPI(...) http.Handler {
        ...
        app.Handle("Get", "/files", http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix,       http.FileServer(root)))
        return app
}

api := http.Server{
        ...
        Handler:      MYAPI(),
}
```

The App is my custom router, and I define my own http.Handler `Handler`. Now if I wrap this handler around fileSystem, how should to code with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
func FromHTTPHandler(h http.Handler) Handler {
    return func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return nil
    }
}

// ...

app.Handle("Get", "/files", FromHTTPHandler(http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix, http.FileServer(root))))
```

Comment: How should I remove h.ServeHTTP if I using HandleFunc in `app.Handle`?

Comment: @ccd I don't quite understand what you're asking, can you elaborate on why you would want to remove `h.ServeHTTP`? And what do you mean by *"using HandleFunc in `app.Handle`"*? If possible update your question with more code.

Comment: Sorry for that, I know the http.Handler is a interface that it must implement the ServeHTTP method, so there is `h.ServeHTTP` in the FromHTTPHandler, is it right? And the HandleFunc default already implement the ServeHTTP with Handler, if `app.Handle` work the same as `http.HandleFunc`, how should I change this code above?

Comment: @ccd I'm not sure what you mean by *"`app.Handle` work the same as `http.HandleFunc`"*. By "work" do you mean the internal implementation of the function body? Or do you simply mean the function's signature? Or does one delegate "work" to the other? It would really help if you show the code you're talking about because right now, the code in your question does not "work the same" the functions are quite different. If I can't see the code you're asking me questions about I don't know how I can help.

Comment: Ok, I update my app.Handle. For example, `a.myRouter.HandleFunc` return the http.HandleFunc, `app.Handle` package all Handlers to http.Server.

Comment: @ccd Ok I see your update, but it is still *unclear* why `h.ServeHTTP` is a problem, it is unclear why you would want to remove it, and it is unclear how else you want to invoke the result of `http.StripPrefix`. Is the code in my answer, in combination with the code in your question, not working? If so, if it is not working, can you please share the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: Because in my own app custom router, it implement the ServeHTTP method, so I think any handler in app.Handle can directly wrap the body around and skip the ServeHTTP method. All the things until now I haven't make clear is that `http.FileServer`, `http.Handler` and `http.HandleFunc`. Can I combine fileSystem and any other api like handlers to one `app.Handle` and don't create other method like `app.HandleFileSystem`? If http.HandleFunc default implement the ServeHTTP method for Handlers, is it necessary to add ServeHTTP again in app.Hanle?

Comment: @ccd sorry but I'm still not sure what the issue here is. However let me say this, ultimately, you can *not* remove / skip the `ServeHTTP` method, period! If you take a look at `HandleFunc` for example, even that function has to convert the given argument to an `http.HandlerFunc` so that it implements the `http.Handler` interface so that it can call the `ServeHTTP` method. The `http.Server` has a single `http.Handler` instance and the `http.ServeMux` has a registry full of `http.Handler` instances and both of them invoke the `ServeHTTP` method.

Comment: @ccd this means that anything that implements the `http.Handler` interface can be passed to the `Server` and `ServeMux`, additionally `ServeMux` accepts any function who's signature is the same as that of the `http.HandlerFunc` type, because then it can easily convert such a function to an `http.Handler`.

Comment: The lack of development experience make my post a little bit away from the raw idea. I will post another question, thanks for all.